# Android XmlPullParser parsing similar nodes

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I have several xml nodes that are the same i need to parse:

```
<start-valid-time period-name="Overnight">2013-12-29T00:00:00-05:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Sunday">2013-12-29T06:00:00-05:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Sunday Night">2013-12-29T18:00:00-05:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Monday">2013-12-30T06:00:00-05:00</start-valid-time>
```

My code:

```java
if(parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("start-valid-time")) {
   periodnames[0] = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
}
```

I get the first period-name attribute just fine, but if I try this:

```java
if(parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("start-valid-time")) {
   periodnames[0] = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
   parser.nextTag();
   periodnames[1] = parser.getAttributeValue(0);
}
```

It does not collect the second period-name which in this case would be Sunday...

If anyone could help, it would be appreciated .-.

Comment: there is only 1 attrbute for start-valid-time. so why this `periodnames[1] = parser.getAttributeValue(0);`

Comment: Well I want to move down to the next start-vaild-time...im very new to xml parsing

Comment: Sorry I realize what I asked doesnt make since...sorry. Yes there is only one attribute, but I want that attribute value for each start-valid-time. Thats why I have an array > periodnames which in each index will include each start-valid-timje attribute value once parsed, like "Overnight", "Sunday", "Monday" ect.

Comment: it is not the array it is getting attribute of next tag

Answer (score 0):

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<start-valid-time period-name="Overnight">2013-12-29T00:00:00-05:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Sunday">2013-12-29T06:00:00-05:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Sunday Night">2013-12-29T18:00:00-05:00</start-valid-time>
<start-valid-time period-name="Monday">2013-12-30T06:00:00-05:00</start-valid-time>
```

To parse and get attribute

To test i put the xml in assests folder. `in` is the `InputStream`.

```
 InputStream in = MainActivity.this.getResources()
                 .getAssets().open("xmlparser.xml");
 try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(in, null);
            parser.nextTag();
            readFeed(parser);
        } catch(Exeption e)
            {
                 e.prinstStacktrace();
            }finally {
            in.close();
        }
```

Then

```
  private void readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            String name=null,value;
            while (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)) {
                   value = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "period-name");
                    name = readText(parser);
                    Log.i("Name.....",name);
                    Log.i("Value ...",value);
                    parser.next();
                    continue;
            }  

        }
```

readText

```
  private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Log

```
12-29 03:01:23.433: I/Name.....(3273): 2013-12-29T00:00:00-05:00
12-29 03:01:23.433: I/Value ...(3273): Overnight
12-29 03:01:23.433: I/Name.....(3273): 2013-12-29T06:00:00-05:00
12-29 03:01:23.443: I/Value ...(3273): Sunday
12-29 03:01:23.443: I/Name.....(3273): 2013-12-29T18:00:00-05:00
12-29 03:01:23.443: I/Value ...(3273): Sunday Night
12-29 03:01:23.443: I/Name.....(3273): 2013-12-30T06:00:00-05:00
12-29 03:01:23.443: I/Value ...(3273): Monday
```